# adding languages for localization to iPhone - is that possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization, nslocalizedstring

Compared to Android iPhone does not support many languages, even though the MAC seems to do so ( simply because I learned that the possibility of adding these languages in xCode is for MAC Apps and not for iOS).

Now I added the Localizable.strings file for languages that are not available in the language list of the iPhone settings for languages.

Is there a way using the standard approach like:

```
[onOffSC setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"On","Off") forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

if I just put a selection menu in my app ?

Otherwise I would have to add a special logic - lets say MYNSLocalizedString, checking first if the user wants to select a non supported language, getting this some other way (probably putting these translations into a NSDictionary) and otherwise calling the standard NSLocalizedString.

I guess I would have to put a language selection menu in the app anyways - but can the calls to `NSLocalizedString` be used or do I have to add a meta-method `MYNSLocalizedString` like mentioned?

Or is there any other good solution for this ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think better would be to use the language which is set in **Settings**, instead of user selecting from menu. Refer to this tutorial might help you understand How Localization is done.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Comment: thanks - but I know how to localize - the issue is that iPhone settings does not support some languages which are eminent for the app :-)

Answer (score 0):

For localization of your iPhone app:
Use the approach described here...
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial

Comment: thanks - but I know how to localize - the issue is that iPhone settings does not support some languages which are eminent for the app :-)